# How to append many tags together in html with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Im noob in jQuery and I want append many tags in my html and I don't know about that.

This is my jQuery code and I get an error:

```
var msg = "mamaly"
var addmsg = 
    '<li class="me dark-gray massage">
        <div class="content"><span class="type-text">' + msg + '</span></div>
        <div class="in-border"></div>
        <div class="l-arrow"></div>
        <div class="status failed" style="display:block;">
            <span class="status-text">Sending Failed</span>
        </div>
    </li>';
$('#timeline ul').append(addmsg);
```

Please guide me about it.

Comment: What is this? Can you tell why are you including all those divs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my friend this is right code not you. you should write tandem this code's

like this :

```
var msg = "mamaly"
var addmsg = '<li class="me dark-gray massage"><div class="content"><span class="type-text">' + msg + '</span></div><div class="in-border"></div><div class="l-arrow"></div><div class="status failed" style="display:block;"><span class="status-text">Sending Failed</span></div></li>';
$('#timeline ul').append(addmsg);
```

Comment: How can you do this. Syntax is right. You dont get any errors in console. But nothing is getting apeended.

Comment: Was that first sentence in english?  :\

Answer (score 2):

In javascript if you write string in new line, then it is not considered to be a continuous string. This is the mistake you have made in declaring your `addmsg` variable.

**Possible solutions:**

**1)** concat continuous string values that are in new line with `+` operator (Note `' +` at end of each line and `'` at start of next line

[*Advantage*: more readable]

[*Disadvantage*: a bit performance hit when concatenating strings]

```
var addmsg = 
    '<li class="me dark-gray massage">' +
        '<div class="content"><span class="type-text">' + msg + '</span></div>' +
        '<div class="in-border"></div>' +
        '<div class="l-arrow"></div>' +
        '<div class="status failed" style="display:block;">' +
            '<span class="status-text">Sending Failed</span>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</li>';
```

OR

**2)** write your string in same line without any line break

[*Advantage*: a bit better performance then concatenating strings]

[*Disadvantage*: less readable for long strings]

```
var addmsg = '<li class="me dark-gray massage"><div class="content"><span class="type-text">' + msg + '</span></div><div class="in-border"></div><div class="l-arrow"></div><div class="status failed" style="display:block;"><span class="status-text">Sending Failed</span></div></li>';
```

Rest of the code (i.e. first and last line) will remain same.

Hope this is helpful !!